# Python BeautifulSoup how to extract/find

Tags: beautifulsoup

Can anyone help me to explain why I can't make it work here?

I can't quite understand the documentation from BeautifulSoup.

```
req = Request('http://performance.morningstar.com/stock/performance-return.action?p=dividend_split_page&t=D05, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')

div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'div_annual_dividends'})

th = div.find('th', text="Dividend Amount")
```

Ii cant seems to extract the value `0.56` using `nextSibling.text`

This is the error I received.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nextSibling'
```

how can i store the output to an array?

also

```
for tr in soup('th', text="Dividend Amount"):
row = [td.text for td in tr('td')]
print(row)
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page is rendered by JavaScript, the real data is in this url:

```
http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/annual-dividends.action?&t=XSES:D05&region=sgp&culture=en-US&cur=&ops=clear&ndec=2&y=5
```

[image]

you can find this url in chrome Dev-Tools.

code:

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/annual-dividends.action?&t=XSES:D05&region=sgp&culture=en-US&cur=&ops=clear&ndec=2&y=5')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
rows = []
for tr in soup('tr', class_=False):
    row = [td.text for td in tr('td')]
    rows.append(row)
```

out:

```
[['0.56', '0.56', '0.58', '0.60', '0.60'],
 ['3.77', '3.27', '2.82', '3.59', '3.46']]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

if i do print nextSibling.text

Comment: can you include comment and update your code such that i can store them to an array? 

i understand for tr in soup('tr', class_=False): will grab the html of "Dividend Amount".

but how can i store the td to an array?



thank you.

Comment: @OOI YI YONG post the output you want in the question.